# Почему при сумме двух значений типа Number на выходе получается NaN? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, nan

Всем привет. Задача: написать на JavaScript функцию, которая считает сумму цифр числа. Например: число 1357, сумма 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16, используя рекурсию.
Через методы Array (reduce, shift) все работает. Написал не используя их - напрямую, по индексам такой код:

```
let num, newNum, sum, len;
num = (prompt('Num').split(''));
newNum = num.map(Number);
len = newNum.length;

function summ(newNum, len, sum) {
    sum = sum + newNum[len];
    return (len == 0) ? sum : summ(newNum, --len, sum);
}

alert(summ(newNum, len, sum = 0));
```

возвращает NaN

Мониторил через консоль выводом, через дебаггинг:   sum += newNum[len] - на этом шаге переменная sum становится NaN хоть ты убей.
Первая итерация - она Number (через typeoff смотрел), последующие - Nan. При этом newNum[len] - строго Number. Прямое приведение к Number в начале функции тож не помогает. В чем причина?

Comment: Что лежит в `newNum[len]` ? Ничего - `undefined`. Вы включаете его в сумму и получаете `NaN`.

Comment: Задачу лучше решить без строк. На числах решение даже проще.

Comment: В newNum (по моему замыслу конечно) лежит массив, полученный из строки num и его элементы приведены к числам через map и Number. В newNum[len] по идее должен быть его элемент с индексом равным значению len

Comment: Вы обращаетесь за правый конец массива.

Comment: В ``newNum`` нет элемента ``newNum[len]``. Странно, что вы не увидели этого в дебаггере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первой итерации `len == newNum.length`

Свойство [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) возвращает значение, которое больше самого большого индекса в массиве.

Поэтому при попытке взять элемент `newNum[newNum.length]` получается `undefined`.

Для решения достаточно убрать лишнее изменение переменной `sum`: `sum = sum + newNum[len];`

и сразу передавать это значение в параметр следующего вызова.

Пример:

```js
let num, newNum, sum, len;
num = (prompt('Num').split(''));
newNum = num.map(Number);
len = newNum.length;

function summ(newNum, len, sum) {
  return (len == 0) ? sum : summ(newNum, --len, sum + newNum[len]);
}

console.log(summ(newNum, len, sum = 0));
```

Также стоит отделить параметры от глобальных переменных и перестать менять значения переменных, достаточно передавать новые значения в качестве параметров:

```js
let num, newNum, sum, len;
num = (prompt('Num').split(''));
newNum = num.map(Number);
len = newNum.length;

function summ(arr, len = arr.length, sum = 0) { // значения по умолчанию
  return (len == 0) ? sum : summ(newNum, len - 1, sum + newNum[len - 1]);
}

console.log(summ(newNum));
```

Comment: Побочный эффект в аргументе и от него зависит другой аргумент. Не хорошо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy поэтому добавил второй вариант где нет изменений переменных, да и параметры по умолчанию правильно задал

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, глаз замылился -  и в массиве newNum обращал внимание вскользь просто на наличие элементов и их "визуальный" тип в консоли. а что первое значение undefined - проходило мимо, да и дебаггер видимо не туда воткнул, проскакивал.